# Read a bunch of JSON files, transform them, and save them

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I'm trying to achieve this with `Gulp`.

1. Read every `.json` file in a given directory including subdirectories.
2. Transform them in some way, for example add a new root level, etc.
3. Save them into a new directory keeping original structure.

The point where I'm lost is how to pipe reading/writing JSON to `src`.

I have the following skeleton now.

```
gulp.task("migratefiles", function () {
  return gulp.src("files/**/*.json")
      .pipe(/* WHAT HERE? */)
      .pipe(gulp.dest("processed"));
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a number of way you can do this:

**(1) Use the [`gulp-json-transform`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-transform) plugin:**

```
var jsonTransform = require('gulp-json-transform');

gulp.task("migratefiles", function () {
  return gulp.src("files/**/*.json")
    .pipe(jsonTransform(function(json, file) {
      var transformedJson = {
        "newRootLevel": json
      };
      return transformedJson;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("processed"));
 });
```

Pros:

- Easy to use
- Supports asynchronous processing (if you return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise))
- Gives access to path of each `file`

Cons:

- Only rudimentary output formatting

**(2) Use the [`gulp-json-editor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-editor) plugin:**

```
var jeditor = require('gulp-json-editor');

gulp.task("migratefiles", function () {
   return gulp.src("files/**/*.json")
     .pipe(jeditor(function(json) {
       var transformedJson = {
         "newRootLevel": json
       };
       return transformedJson;
     }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("processed"));
});
```

Pros:

- Easy to use
- Automatically recognizes the indentation your input files use (two spaces, four spaces, tabs etc.) and formats your output files accordingly
- Supports various [`js-beautify` options](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options)

Cons:

- Doesn't seem to support asynchronous processing
- Doesn't seem to have a way to access path of each file

**(3) Do it manually (by directly accessing the [`vinyl`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) file object using [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream)):**

```
var map = require('map-stream');

gulp.task("migratefiles", function () {
   return gulp.src("files/**/*.json")
     .pipe(map(function(file, done) {
       var json = JSON.parse(file.contents.toString());
       var transformedJson = {
         "newRootLevel": json
       };
       file.contents = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(transformedJson));
       done(null, file);
     }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("processed"));
});
```

Pros:

- Full control/access over everything
- Supports asynchronous processing (through a `done` callback)

Cons:

- Harder to use

Comment: Thank you for the really detailed answer, I'll choose manual processing I think.